# Flutter navigation issue with login page and CupertinoTabView

Tags: flutter, navigation

I have an issue getting navigation to work in Flutter where I have a login page as initial view, which will push a route to a main page which is a CupertinoTabScaffold. The login page is shown correct and will navigate to the mainPage route ok, when the login button is pressed, but I cannot get back to the login page when pressing a "logout" button on a tab in the mainPage. It will just transform to the same page/tab.

I include two routes in the MyApp class like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of the application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        DefaultMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        DefaultWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      theme: const CupertinoThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(85, 110, 140, 1),
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const LoginPage(),
        '/mainPage': (context) => const CupertinoHomePage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

In the LoginPage navigation is ok:

```
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Login Page'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/mainPage');
            },
            child: const Text('Login'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Main page is a CupertinoTabScaffold with a CupertinoTabBar with 5 items, and everything is working fine. In one of the tab pages (class MorePage which is defined in a separate file) I just included a button to navigate back to the loginPage. (just testing navigation). In the final app, the users will be logged out and thus taken to the loginPage. This doesn't work:

```
class MorePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MorePage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
        navigationBar: const CupertinoNavigationBar(
          middle: Text('More'),
        ),
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/');
                  //Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');
                },
                child: const Text('Log out'),
              ),
            ]));
  }
}
```

The CupertinoHomePage class is here:

```
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:ios_test/more_page.dart';

class CupertinoHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CupertinoHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CupertinoHomePage> createState() => _CupertinoHomePageState();
}

class _CupertinoHomePageState extends State<CupertinoHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const double iconSize = 20;

    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        //currentIndex: 1,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                CupertinoIcons.house_fill,
                size: iconSize,
              ),
              label: 'Home'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                CupertinoIcons.qrcode,
                size: iconSize,
              ),
              label: 'My Items'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                CupertinoIcons.chat_bubble_2,
                size: iconSize,
              ),
              label: 'Chats'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                CupertinoIcons.person_2_fill,
                size: iconSize,
              ),
              label: 'Contacts'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                CupertinoIcons.ellipsis_circle,
                size: iconSize,
              ),
              label: 'More'),
        ],
      ),
      tabBuilder: (context, index) {
        late final CupertinoTabView returnValue;
        switch (index) {
          case 0:
            returnValue = CupertinoTabView(builder: (context) {
              return const CupertinoPageScaffold(
                  navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
                    middle: Text('Home'),
                  ),
                  child: Center(child: Text('Home')));
            });
            break;
          case 1:
            returnValue = CupertinoTabView(
              builder: (context) {
                return const CupertinoPageScaffold(
                    navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
                      middle: Text('My items'),
                    ),
                    child: Center(child: Text('My items')));
                //return CupertinoChatPage();
              },
            );
            break;
          case 2:
            returnValue = CupertinoTabView(
              builder: (context) {
                return const CupertinoPageScaffold(
                    navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
                      middle: Text('Chats'),
                    ),
                    child: Center(child: Text('Chats')));
                //return CupertinoChatPage();
              },
            );
            break;
          case 3:
            returnValue = CupertinoTabView(
              builder: (context) {
                return const CupertinoPageScaffold(
                    navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
                      middle: Text('Contacts'),
                    ),
                    child: Center(child: Text('Contacts')));
                //return CupertinoChatPage();
              },
            );
            break;
          case 4:
            returnValue = CupertinoTabView(
              builder: (context) {
                return MorePage();
                //return CupertinoSettingsPage();
              },
            );
            break;
        }
        return returnValue;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code of the CupertinoHomePage widget, which contains your logout button ?

Comment: Have added the CupertinoHomePage, but the logout button is in the Class MorePage where the navigation also is